# What is the beginning and end of a Lucene token stream when parsing a query?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

We're trying to implement a custom filter that needs to remember past tokens that were processed before within the same query. We tried overriding the `end()` and/or `reset()` methods from `TokenFilter` but found out that these methods were called between each token.

This was contrary to our expectation of the `end()` and/or `reset()` methods only being called at the beginning or end of the token stream representing the query. This unexpected behavior can be reproduced by the following example code below.

(solr) schema snippet:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    ...
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="com.foobar.solr.CustomFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Filter implementation:

```
public class CustomFilter extends TokenFilter {
    CharTermAttribute termAttribute = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

    public CustomFilter(TokenStream in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("### increment token pre loop: " + termAttribute.toString());

        while (input.incrementToken()) {
            System.out.println("### increment token looping through input: " + termAttribute.toString());
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void end() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("### end");
        super.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("### reset");
        super.reset();
    }
}
```

Log output for the query "foo bar":

```
### reset
### increment token pre loop:
### increment token looping through input: foo
### end
### reset
### increment token pre loop:
### increment token looping through input: bar
### end
```

Why are the `end()` and `reset()` methods called for each token instead of for the complete query?

**Edit:** Or why is `input.incrementToken()` returning `false` after the first token was processed?

Comment: The javadocs for these methods clearly state that they are invoked before and after each token.

Comment: Not sure which javadoc you mean: the javadoc for `TokenStream.end()` states: "This method is called by the consumer after the last token has been consumed, after {@link #incrementToken()} returned <code>false</code>"

Comment: are you using a query parser or are you building your queries with code?

Comment: @omu_negru For this test, we're using the query parser that's part of Solr admin console. Solr is running locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i noticed you're using solr, you need to understand that the query parser will split the query by whitespaces, and it takes precedence to your analyzer :  so if you query for "foo bar" you will have the "foo" and "bar" passed separately through your analyzer chain. You can bypass this behavior by making "foo bar" a phrase query, adding the `\"foo bar\"`

EDIT: for clarification, a phrase query will take precedence above the query parser whitespace splitting and is defined by wrapping a sequence of tokens inside quote characters

Comment: Thanks, that explains. As a side note (because phrase queries will not work for us), any idea how we could detect that a token is coming from a new or different(i.e. concurrent) query?

Comment: not really, but i highly doubt your tokenizers or filters get used from multiple threads since they can carry state (and some of them do) and none of them strike me as particularly thread safe. I would put my bet on writing my own Analyzer class and doing my stuff inside the `createComponents` method.